# Jest require '@material-ui/icons' gives undefined

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui

When ever I try to use require or require.requireActual in jest, to import '@material-ui/icons', jest claims it to be undefined.

I'm guessing this is a bug/issue, as I cant imagine any export to be undefined for require.  The file being referenced by this ('@material-ui/icons/index.js') uses code like this to define its exports:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "AccessAlarm", {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function get() {
    return _AccessAlarm.default;
  }
});
```

I know jest does do funky stuff with the base require, perhaps this method of export definition is tripping jest up?

Does anyone have any insight into this, solutions or workarounds, etc?
Also does anybody know of a way to get a list of icons in '@material-ui/icons' given this restriction (get a list of the icons is all I'm trying to do in the first place), and no, I do not want to use a file reader.

To be clear, this is on a simple test file with no mocking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I am now using the following solution (automock all material-ui icons) since it looks like jest cant handle them to begin with, so no harm in just permanently automocking them:

```
const mockIconsList = new Map();
jest.mock('@material-ui/icons', () => new Proxy({__esModule: true}, {
  get: (target, prop) => {
    if (prop in target)
      return target[prop];
    if (!mockIconsList.has(prop))
      mockIconsList.set(prop, mockComponent(`mockMaterialIcon${prop}`));
    return mockIconsList.get(prop);
  },
}));
```

I am still however curious about the above issue and any information regarding it.